# Why are my Galaxy S23+ WiFi Speeds < 200Mbps over 5GHz WiFi6 on 1Gbps fiber?

Tags: wi-fi

I have 1Gb ATT Fiber and have measured network speeds using ookla speedtest across multiple devices and multiple access points on my network. Everything is as expected except for my S23+ WiFi speeds which never exceed 175Mbps up/down, even when connected directly to the BGW320-500 using WiFi6 5GHz. This is true for two different S23+ phones.

By comparison, I have laptops with 5GHz WiFi5 and 6 that achieve  800-900Mbps, so I know that bandwidth is there. I'm convinced the problem is the S23 and have gone through every setting I can find, but nothing helps.

Any advice on how to get at this?

Comment: Do you test using the browser (which?) or a dedicated app?

Comment: Notebooks have up to 4 large antennas which means they can use 4 parallel streams. In smartphones because of the limited space only up two smaller antennas are common (not sure how many antennas your phone has).

Comment: Have you tried this with the S23 next to the BGW? 5GHz can have trouble going through walls.

Comment: What's the router model? How far away is the S23 from the router? If standing within a few feet of the router, does the throughput remain low? Is QoS configured on the router? Does modifying QoS to prioritize traffic to the S23's IP make a difference? Do the 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz networks on the router have a different name? If not, does changing the 5Ghz network to a different name and connecting the S23 to it result in the S23 receiving higher throughput? What channel is the 5Ghz network set to and what is the channel width [20Mhz, 40Mhz, 80Mhz, 160Mhz]?

Comment: +1 about what browser/app you tested with. People often see one browser/program perform a LOT worse than another on the same machine. For me Firefox only managed 300Mbps, Chromium 850Mbps, and a terminal app 975Mbps. Even dedicated speed testing apps can be different among each other, not to mention the server used for testing. Also try an iperf / iperf3 app connecting to another device on your local network

Comment: @davidbaumann - doesn't matter, tried both

Comment: @John Dallman - yes, literally, right next to the router

Comment: @JW0914 - Router is a RT2600ac, but doesn't matter because I get the same problem connected to the BGW320-500 5GHz wifi band as well.

Comment: @Xen2050 - the only variation is across different speed tests (ookla vs google fiber vs fast vs ....), but I am only reporting what I'm seeing using Ookla speedtest and I've selected a very stable endpoint that shows no variation. Good suggestion trying iperf.

Comment: @Robert - I was still expecting better than 200MBps, so I just tried my daughter's iPhone 14 and got around the same numbers. So, perhaps you're on to something. I had found people reporting much higher speeds on the S23+, but perhaps I should have looked more closely at how they got those numbers. Hmmm....

Comment: I don't really care about the absolute numbers, but I'm experiencing quality issues with video playback on multiple apps. E.g., I get frame rate reduction periodically when using Prime and on YouTube, it auto-selected 320p but if I bump it manually, I can stream 1080p fine after some buffering. 200Mbps should be plenty, so maybe the low numbers are an indication of some other quality problem? I tried running a packet loss test and looks fine, but maybe there's a better tool I can use?

Comment: The raw Wifi speed is usually not the main problem in case of streaming problems. Usually it is more a problem because WiFi is a shared medium so other Wifi can disturb your signal. And to my experience of Prime app requires a network that works 110% otherwise it reduces quality. Just use download mode to force best quality.

Comment: @Robert - Appreciate the additional input. I shouldn't have any WiFi interference. I've done a signal scan and there are no other overlapping devices using the channel. On my previous device, an ancient S8, I didn't have these problems. I suspect there are some realtime issues with this version of android or the S23.